# Using require as if is running 'cd ./folder && node file.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following structure

```
├── testFolder
    └──subTestFolder
        test.ts
    index.ts
└── foo
    └── beta.ts
├──text.json
```

Based in this, I'm trying to `require` the `test.js` inside `beta.js` based in test.js absolute path.
But when I ran `ts-node ./foo/beta.js`, it throws `Cannot find module '../text.json`

test.js Content:

```js
require("../index.js");
```

beta.js content:

```js
const file = 'D:\testFolder\subTestFolder\test.js';
const dir = path.dirname(file);
process.chdir(dir);
require(file);
```

index.ts

```js
const json= fs.readFileSync('../corde.json').toString();
```

Comment: Why are you calling `chdir`? That's completely unnecessary. Use [`resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) to find the correct path.

Comment: You can also directly load json using require, or import from if using Typescript (you'll need to enable the flag)